# Using Recursive Functions in Python to find Factors of a Given Number

Tags: python-3.x, function, recursion

Have tried searching for this, but can't find exactly what I'm looking for.

I want to make a function that will recursively find the factors of a number; for example, the factors of 12 are 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 & 12.

I can write this fairly simply using a for loop with an if statement:

```
#a function to find the factors of a given number

def print_factors(x):
    print ("The factors of %s are:" % number)
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        if number % i == 0: #if the number divided by i is zero, then i is a factor of that number
            print (i)

number = int(input("Enter a number: "))

print (print_factors(number))
```

However, when I try to change it to a recursive function, I am getting just a loop of the "The factors of x are:" statement. This is what I currently have:

```
#uses recursive function to print all the letters of an integer

def print_factors(x): #function to print factors of the number with the argument n
    print ("The factors of %s are:" % number)
    while print_factors(x) != 0: #to break the recursion loop
        for i in range(1,x + 1):
            if x % i == 0:
                print (i)

number = int(input("Enter a number: "))

print_factors(number)
```

The error must be coming in either when I am calling the function again, or to do with the while loop (as far as I understand, you need a while loop in a recursive function, in order to break it?)

Comment: There's a key design error: When using recursion, you must *return* the result, not print it.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite many problems with your recursive approach. In fact its not recursive at all.

1) Your function doesn't return anything but your while loop has a comparision `while print_factors(x) != 0:`

2) Even if your function was returning a value, it would never get to the point of evaluating it and comparing due to the way you have coded.

You are constantly calling your function with the same parameter over and over which is why you are getting a loop of print statements.

In a recursive approach, you define a problem in terms of a simpler version of itself.

And you need a base case to break out of recursive function, not a while loop.

Here is a very naive recursive approach.

```
def factors(x,i):
    if i==0:
        return
    if x%i == 0:
        print(i)
    return factors (x,i-1) #simpler version of the problem

factors(12,12)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we do using below method:

`def findfactor(n):
    factorizeDict
    def factorize(acc, x):
        if(n%x == 0 and n/x >= x):
            if(n/x > x):
                acc += [x, n//x]
                return factorize(acc, x+1)
            else:
                acc += [x]
                return acc
        elif(n%x != 0):
            return factorize(acc, x+1)
        else:
            return acc
    return factorize(list(), 1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def factors(x,i=None) :
    if i is None :
        print('the factors of %s are : ' %x)
        print(x,end=' ')
        i = int(x/2)
    if i == 0 :
        return
    if x % i == 0 :
        print(i,end=' ')
    return factors(x,i-1)

num1 = int(input('enter number : '))
print(factors(num1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutations, variable reassignments, and other side effects. That said, here's how I'd write `factors` -

```py
def factors(n, m = 2):
  if m >= n:
    return
  if n % m == 0:
    yield m
  yield from factors(n, m + 1)

print(list(factors(10))) # [2,5]
print(list(factors(24))) # [2,3,4,6,8,12]
print(list(factors(99))) # [3,9,11,33]
```

And here's `prime_factors` -

```py
def prime_factors(n, m = 2):
  if m > n:
    return
  elif n % m == 0:
    yield m
    yield from prime_factors(n // m, m)
  else:
    yield from prime_factors(n, m + 1)

print(list(prime_factors(10))) # [2,5]
print(list(prime_factors(24))) # [2,2,2,3]
print(list(prime_factors(99))) # [3,3,11]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fact (n , a = 2):
    if n <= a :
        return n
        
    elif n % a != 0 :
        return fact(n , a + 1 )

    elif  n % a == 0:
        return str(a) + f" * {str(fact(n / a , a ))}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way.  The 'x' is the number you want to find the factors of.  The 'c = 1' is used as a counter, using it we'll divide your number by 1, then by 2, all the way up to and including your nubmer, and if the modular returns a 0, then we know that number is a factor, so we print it out.

```
    def factors (x,c=1):
        if c == x: return x
        else:
            if x%c == 0: print(c)
            return factors(x,c+1)
```